# jupyter notebook - problem no module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to learn pandas and I haven't been able to import it into my code. I have looked at other answers on this site and none of them have worked.
jupyter notebook is not importing my module.

Comment: first thing to check is that you are using the right kernel (your virtualenv ) within the Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

let's try:
in jupiter

1. `!pip install pandas --upgrade`
2. `import pandas as pd`
3. `print(pd.__version__)`

what do you see

Comment: print(pd.__version__)